# django output with array or list of object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am doing my first Django project and I am stuck here. I need two arrays in result output

- 1. Pending reservations
- 2. Approved reservations

Reservation contain type of services user opted for. There can be multiple reservations.

- status=0 - pending
- status=1 - approved

**Required output**

```
result: {
 "upcoming_pending":    
 [{reservation_id,location_id,location_name,arrival_date,arrival_time,
 departure_date,departure_time,
  services:[{service_id,service_title,service_description},{}],
  add-ons:[{service_id,service_title,service_description},{}],comments}, 
 {},etc]},

  "upcoming_approved":    
 [{reservation_id,location_id,location_name,arrival_date,arrival_time,
 departure_date,departure_time,
  services:[{service_id,service_title,service_description},{}],
  add-ons:[{service_id,service_title,service_description},{}],comments}, 
 {},etc]}
```

**My code** I am trying something like this below

```
data={}
data["upcoming_pending"]=[]
data["upcoming_approved"]=[]

queryset1 = reservations.objects.filter(user_id=user_id,arrival__gte=datetime.now(),status=0)
for a in queryset1:
  data["upcoming_pending"][a.id]=reservations.objects.filter(id=a.id)
  data["upcoming_pending"][a.id]["services"]=services.objects.filter(service_id__in=ser,type=1)
  data["upcoming_pending"][a.id]["add-ons"]=services.objects.filter(service_id__in=ser,type=2)


queryset2 = reservations.objects.filter(user_id=user_id,arrival__gte=datetime.now(),status=1)
for b in queryset2:
  data["upcoming_approved"][b.id]=reservations.objects.filter(id=a.id)
  data["upcoming_approved"][b.id]["services"]=services.objects.filter(service_id__in=ser,type=1)
  data["upcoming_approved"][b.id]["add-ons"]=services.objects.filter(service_id__in=ser,type=2)

  return Response({"result":data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: You need [Serializers][1] and [Nested Serializers][2] to clean up things a bit. [1]: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/
  [2]: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers

Comment: I am very new to Django rest framework. i can pass queryset to serializers and get the output. but in this project there are join query with sub query for Services and Addon services. i dont know how to write such complex code using serializers.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's build it with `Serializer`s, bottom-up:

1. first, a serializer for services;
2. one serializer for reservations with two extra fields (services and add-ons);
3. one serializer containing the two reservations groups (pending and approved).

I assume your models are named `Service` and `Reservations`.

### 1. Services

Create a `serializers.py` file in your Django app, and in there, create a `ModelSerializer` for the `Service` model instances as follows.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Service
```

### 2. Reservations

For the `Reservations` model instances, since we want to add two custom related fields, we'll create a custom serializer containing all the fields we want to show, as follows.

```
class ReservationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # By using 'source' you can rename a field
    reservation_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='pk')
    location_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    location_name = serializers.CharField()
    arrival_date = serializers.DateField()
    arrival_time = serializers.TimeField()
    departure_date = serializers.DateField()
    departure_time = serializers.TimeField()
    # ... other model fields you may need
    # These are nested serializers, 'many' means that they are lists
    services = ServiceSerializer(many=True)
    add_ons = ServiceSerializer(many=True)
```

Please note: serialization will fail if the serializer fields are not found in the objects passed to the serializer. E.g. if `departure_date` is not a field of `Reservation`, the above code won't work.

### 3. Pending and approved

The last serializer is the one we are returning as response: it simply takes two `ReservationSerializer`s as its fields.

```
class PendingApprovedReservationsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    upcoming_pending = ReservationSerializer(many=True)
    upcoming_approved = ReservationSerializer(many=True)
```

### Putting it all together

Ok, now we have all the serializers in place. In our view we can do something similar:

```
pending = reservations.objects.filter(user_id=user_id, 
    arrival__gte=datetime.now(), status=0)
for a in pending:
  a.services = services.objects.filter(service_id__in=ser, type=1)
  a.add_ons = services.objects.filter(service_id__in=ser, type=2)

approved = reservations.objects.filter(user_id=user_id,
    arrival__gte=datetime.now(), status=1)
for b in approved:
  b.services = services.objects.filter(service_id__in=ser, type=1)
  b.add_ons = services.objects.filter(service_id__in=ser, type=2)

data = dict(upcoming_pending=pending,upcoming_approved=approved)
serializer = PendingApprovedReservationsSerializer(data)
# HTTP 200 status is set by default
return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Disclaimer**: this is untested code, it only aims to be a suggestion.

**Reference**: [DRF nested serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. its looks really awesome.. just 1 more doubt. is there any way i can reduce the no of time query is fired to database.. if the 100 records then it will loop 100 times to fetch the records

Comment: It depends on your model relations. Can you update your question with relevant info? Although this looks a bit like _another_ question.

Comment: yes i got  it what i was looking for and i am really thankful about that.. do you want me to create separate question for queryset?